# React state variable unexpectedly undefined when trying to pass as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component hierarchy like this:

```
 AgreementContentWidget
   AgreementTitleContainer
     AgreementTitle <-- this is ok, but
     CommentList    <-- problem here
   SectionsContainer
```

Mounting `AgreementContentWidget`:

```
 <AgreementContentWidget agreement_id={85} />
```

requests the widget to load agreement 85.

```
var AgreementContentWidget = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {agreement: []};
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.loadAgreementDetails();
  },

  loadAgreementDetails: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/agreements/" + this.props.agreement_id, 
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(agreement) {
        this.setState({agreement: agreement.agreement});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error("/agreements/" + this.props.agreement_id, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  handleAgreementUpdate: function() {
    this.loadAgreementDetails();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="panel panel-default">
        <div className="panel-body" id={"container_agreement_" + this.state.agreement.id}>
          <div className="col-lg-12">           
            <AgreementTitleContainer agreement={this.state.agreement} onAgreementUpdate={this.handleAgreementUpdate} />
            <SectionsContainer agreement={this.state.agreement} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I pass `agreement={this.state.agreement}` to `<AgreementTitleContainer>` to render components comprising an agreement's title.

Inside `<AgreementTitleContainer>`:

```
var AgreementTitleContainer = React.createClass({
  handleAgreementUpdate: function() {
    this.props.onAgreementUpdate();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="row" id="container_title">
        <AgreementTitle agreement={this.props.agreement} onAgreementUpdate={this.handleAgreementUpdate} />
        <CommentList commentable_type={"agreement"} commentable_id={this.props.agreement.id} />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

`<AgreementTitle>` takes `{this.props.agreement}` and it's got contents of agreement 85. It renders and does other operations as expected. **However, `<CommentList>` has `undefined` for `commentable_id` as `this.props.agreement.id` is undefined** (via debugger: `this.props.agreement` is always undefined for this component).

So:

- Why is `{this.props.agreement}` defined for `<AgreementTitle>`?
- Why is it undefined for `<CommentList>`?

I know that `<CommentList>` works as expected in other contexts where a value is passed to `commentable_id` (e.g. `commentable_id={42}`) rather than from an object in `this.state` (as above).

I noted that for `<CommentList>` when it tries a `GET` request in `loadComments()` below:

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {comments: []};
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadComments();
  },

  loadComments: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/comments/?commentable_type=" + this.props.commentable_type + "&id=" + this.props.commentable_id, 
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(comments) {
        this.setState({comments: comments.comments});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error("/comments/?commentable_type=" + this.props.commentable_type + "&id=" + this.props.commentable_id, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  ...
  ...
}
```

I get an error message from failed `GET`

```
GET https://tinya-thedanielmay-2.c9.io/comments/?commentable_type=agreement&id=undefined 404 Not Found
```

which I expect, as `id` (from `this.props.commentable_id` above) is `undefined`. However, the `console.error` function then prints out:

```
/comments/?commentable_type=agreement&id=85 error Not Found
```

So at that point of execution, `this.props.commentable_id` seems to be defined now.

I'm thinking that the decision for `<AgreementContentWidget>` to:

- `GET` agreement 85
- Set `this.state.agreement` with agreement 85 details <--
- Then proceed to use `this.state.agreement` as input to props, e.g. `agreement={this.state.agreement}`

has something to do with my issues.

Architecturally, I'd like to retain the `GET` agreement at `<AgreementContentWidget>` level and have the retrieved agreement details propagate down.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think that this has anything to do with your problem, but the React docs say specifically to load ajax in `ComponentDidMount` as you're doing in CommentList. In AgreementWidget you're loading ajax in `ComponentWillMount`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're initializing in `getInitialState` is what's passed the first time `<AgreementContentWidget>` renders. You think `<AgreementTitle>` works properly because it is re-rendered when you get the agreement data from your backend, but CommentsList, being dependent on that ID to load its own data, will error out before it can render. It doesn't know to go out and get the data again because it's only loading in `componentDidMount`.

You should defer the retrieval of comments until you get the correct property. To do this, use React's `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` function and wait until `agreement.id` exists, and is not 0 before loading your ajax.

So REMOVE `this.componentDidMount` from CommentList and ADD this:

```
this.componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(nextProps.agreement && nextProps.agreement.id){
    this.loadComments();
  }
}
```

You should also set propTypes so you can be alerted to these issues with nice messages and provide some self documentation to your code.

Comment: Thanks for helpful advice. How do I ensure comments loaded prior to agreement load?

Comment: Unfortunately, initialising ``this.state.agreement`` with a temporary object (e.g. ``id == 0``) doesn't resolve the fundamental problem: instead of ``<CommentList>`` loading with undefined object, it tries to load with temporary object id. I don't understand how I can pass ``this.state.agreement`` into a component, loaded after mounting ... have two child components use it as a prop, but one child component behaves as expected with loaded data but the other child component does not (it uses initialised data). :)

Comment: You didn't post the code to AgreementTitle, but my guess is that it's not loading Ajax, therefore it simple re-renders once the data comes back and works. CommentList needs that data FIRST. I updated my answer so it's more clear.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. You're right: ``<AgreementTitle>`` doesn't load ajax but renders (I omitted to try to be brief). I amended as per your suggestion and this gets the comments loading - yay. Still resolving some additional variables undefined but am working through using some of your suggestions. Will update and flag anything that I get stuck on.